# How prevent someone from opening my theme directory

Tags: themes, directory

How to prevent users from opening my themes directory or at least preventing wordpress from outputting an error.

For example when I open this link in my wordpress blog
`https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/themename/`

I have this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in ..`

How can I prevent this from happening ?

Comment: You shouldn't display PHP errors in public for the live site, only log it. Check out the [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) and [`log_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) in `php.ini`.

Comment: You should use proper `.htaccess` files for Apache servers, or an [equivalent setup for Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/) or a fitting [lighttp setup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23472819/376483).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to add a check to see if a constant has been defined. If it hasn't you'll know the file is being accessed directly.

```
if ( ! defined ( 'ABSPATH') ) die ( 'No soup for you!' );
```

Add this to every file you don't want to be directly accessed.

Also, anything you add (like this) will be erased when a theme is updated -- unless you built your own theme and have control over that.

Comment: Another version would be: `defined ( 'ABSPATH' ) or die ( 'No soup for you!' );`

Comment: True, that is shorter, but for this example I think the first version is better for someone less experienced.

Comment: ... and we should note that this insert would be lost for every theme update.